# setting CATALINA_BASE in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat7

I have installed tomcat7 in ubuntu 12.04. Now when i try to start the service,i get this error :

> invalid CATALINA_BASE: /var/lib/tomcat7

Tomcat7 is installed in the directory `/usr/share/tomcat7`.

How do i fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/usr/share/tomcat7` is the CATALINA_HOME directory. CATALINA_BASE is the directory of your Tomcat instance. Most probably that directory does not exist.

You can create the entire directory structure for a Tomcat instance using the command `tomcat7-instance-create <instance_name>`. If the command is not available you'll need to install tomcat7-user (`apt-get install tomcat7-user`).

CATALINA_BASE can be modified in `/etc/default/tomcat7`.